# XML edit attributes

Tags: python, xml

I want to edit the attributes of an element in an XML file.

The file looks like

```
<Parameter name="Spec 2 Circumference/Length" type="real" mode="both">
    <Value>0.0</Value> 
    <Result>0.0</Result> 
</Parameter>
```

I want to replace the value and Result attribute with some other value from a text file.

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is 0.0 0.0 valid XML? please post more of your file ..

Answer (score 1):

An example using [ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm). It will replace the `Value` elements text with some string; the procedure for the `Result` element is analogue and omitted here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

xml = """
<Parameter name="Spec 2 Circumference/Length" type="real" mode="both">
    <Value>0.0</Value> 
    <Result>0.0</Result> 
</Parameter>
"""

from elementtree.ElementTree import fromstring, tostring

# read XML, here we read it from a String
doc = fromstring(xml)

for e in doc.findall('Value'):
    e.text = 'insert your string from your textfile here!'

print tostring(doc)

# will result in:
#
# <Parameter mode="both" name="Spec 2 Circumference/Length" type="real">
#     <Value>insert your string from your textfile here!</Value> 
#     <Result>0.0</Result> 
# </Parameter>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Actually in real case I have an XML file containing these kind elements repetitively.
I want to read the lines from that XMl file and do the thing as you said.
Please give some hint on it .

Thanks for your immediate reply.

Comment: please modify your question (above) instead of asking new questions in comments .. it more comprehensable that way; also, please always include relevant parts of code/data in your question and maybe some hints on where you stuck and why (errors, exceptions, ...) - last note: more people (rep-hunters) would answer this question, if it weren't a 'community wiki'